# Attach method does nothing in observer

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Observer for a model. When the model is created I want to create and attach another model based on a parameter in the request.

The new model is created successfully. But the relationship is not.

The observer function:

```php
public function created(Work $work)
{
    $new_publisher = request()->new_publisher;

    if($new_publisher) {
        $publisher = Publisher::create([
            'publisher_name' => $new_publisher,
            'type' => 2,
            'status' => false,
        ]);
        $work->publishers()->attach($publisher->id);
    }
}
```

If I do

```php
dd($publisher->id);
```

before executing the attach command I get the correct id.

Any clue on what's going on over here? I have also tried with:

```php
DB::table('publisher_work')->insert(['publisher_id' => $publisher->id,'work_id' => $work->id]);
```

but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating your model? your insert into `publisher_work` uses the querybuilder and not eloquent, the querybuilder never fires any model events.

Comment: The model event is being fired. The Publisher model is created afther the model execution but the relationship is not attached. I did a DB:enableQueryLog() and got that the queries are being executed.

Comment: This is the query log:
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "insert into `publishers` (`publisher_name`, `type`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:5 [
      0 => "asdds"
      1 => 2
      2 => false
      3 => "2020-02-06 14:35:24"
      4 => "2020-02-06 14:35:24"
    ]
    "time" => 0.28
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "insert into `publisher_work` (`publisher_id`, `work_id`) values (?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:2 [
      0 => 19074
      1 => 3664
    ]
    "time" => 0.23
  ]
]

Comment: Can you add your table structure and your relationships to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship was defined correctly and the model observer was being executed as well. I added

```php
\Log::info(
    $query->sql, $query->bindings, $query->time
);
```

to the AppServiceProvider in order to see what was going on.

It turned out that the insert was being made but then a delete was also executed. Diggind deeper I saw that another package I had installed was making a $model->sync([]), removing the previous attatchement.

Thanks!